# "Recursive value i needs type" error when trying to perform multiple where with the conditions on a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with columns month, id and value, something like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  (201801, "fghufhg", 3),
  (201801, "bhfbhgf", 6),
  (201801, "dgdjjh", 5),
  (201802, "ehfjrnfj", 6),
  (201802, "ehghghfj", 98),
  (201803, "nfrghj", 75),
  (201803, "nfnrjfj", 7)
).toDF("month", "id", "value")
```

I created the function below to select a month in my dataset

```
def selectMonth(input:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],  col:Column , month:Int) :  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = {
  input.where(col === month)
}
```

So when I do this

```
val month201801 = selectMonth(df, $"month", "201801")
```

I get a dataframe (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) with only the rows with info for this month.

Now I want to find an easier way to create several dataframes like this from a list of months like:

```
Seq(201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805)
```

I wanted to do something like the code below, but I am clearly not thinking about this in the right way:

```
val listCohorts = Seq(201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805) 

for (i <- listCohorts) {
  val (month +i) = selectMonth(df, $"month", i)
}
```

Because I get this error:

```
notebook:4: error: recursive value i needs type
  val (C +i) = selectMonth(df, $"month", i)
                                         ^
notebook:4: error: not found: value +
  val (C +i) = selectMonth(df, $"month", i)
         ^
notebook:4: error: not found: value C
  val (C +i) = selectMonth(df, $"month", i)
       ^
```

The "month +i" was my attempt to name each dataframe like month201801, month201802, and the "i" was supposed to be the input of the month in the function

In other words, what I want is a way to create several dataframes (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) performing only a where operation in the original dataset and naming it based on the condition used on the where. And to be able to adapt this (like choose other months to create other dataframes) by changing only the list that contains the information for the where.

In python this would be as simple as this:

```
monthlist = ['201801', '201802', '201803']
column = 'month'

for i in monthlist:
    globals()[column + i] = df[df[column] == i]
```

This would create 3 dataframes named month201801, month201802, and month201803, each one containing only the rows of the original dataframe for the month in their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done without separate function, list of dates converted to Map with specifyc keys:

```
val column = "month"
val df = Seq(201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805).toDF(column)

val dates = Seq(201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805)
val monthDfMap = dates.map ( date => column+date -> df.where(col(column)===date)).toMap

val may: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = monthDfMap("month201805")
may.show(false)
```

Output is:

```
+------+
|month |
+------+
|201805|
+------+
```

Comment: That's interesting! But in this case the output is no longer type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], right? I apologize if the question is confusing, I'm going to try to update the question so it's more clear, but as I have little knowledge on this I may not be expressing myself right

Comment: Output type is Dataset, last line in code answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I can work with that! It's still not exactly what I was looking for because I will need to do the last step manually right? Like naming each val (like may) to convert it to Dataset. There is no way to do this conversion inside the map, right? Like having month201805 already as a Dataset

Comment: Map "monthDfMap" contains several Datasets, each with different key: Map(month201801 -> [month: int], month201802 -> [month: int], month201805 -> [month: int], month201803 -> [month: int], month201804 -> [month: int]). Each Dataset can be retrieved by appropriate key, for ex. 'monthDfMap("month201805")'.
"Map" documentation is here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically name variables in Scala. Use a Map instead. (Map is called dict in Python.)

Comment: But the problem is not only on the naming, even putting a fix name I can't get the function to get the input from the list (I tried that with a list with only one month) without it complaining about the type. Would this also apply to this problem? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see that in your question. Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] showing the code that causes that error and the error message?

Comment: I tried adding an example but I don't think it's exactly what you asked. I apologize, it's because I'm knew to this and I don't really know how to create an example of this dataset